# Улучшить скорость выполнения алгоритма

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gdal

есть код:

```py
mask = (latitude >= latitudeMin) * (latitude <= latitudeMax) * (longitude >= longitudeMin) * (longitude <= longitudeMax)

points = np.zeros(shape=(latitude[mask].shape[0], 2))
points[:, 0] = longitude[mask] 
points[:, 1] = latitude[mask]
```

Выполняется вечно долго. размер latitude и longitude = 6700x12000. Надо чтобы выполнялось быстрее, если это возможно. Спасибо за любую помощь.

```py
def get_mask(x_index, y_index, ncols, nrows):
    """

    """
    mask_nodata = np.zeros(shape=(nrows, ncols))
    mask_nodata[y_index, x_index] = 1
    for i in range(2):
        cusum_0 = np.cumsum(mask_nodata, axis=0)
        cusum_1 = np.cumsum(mask_nodata, axis=1)
        mask_nodata = (cusum_0 < cusum_0[-1, :]) * (0 < cusum_0) + (cusum_1.T < cusum_1[:, -1].T).T * (0 < cusum_1)
    return mask_nodata

def getAllDatasets(path_to_hdf):
    """
    Method to get all keys from h5 file

    path_to_hdf - file path string variable 

    return all key from a file

    """
    sub_data = gdal.Open(path_to_hdf, gdal.GA_ReadOnly).GetSubDatasets()
    return {key.split(' ')[1]: str(value.split(':')[-1]) for (value, key) in sub_data}

def getDataFromFile(path_to_hdf, num):
    """
    Method to get Data from file by key

    path_to_hdf - file path string variable 
    num - int key

    return data array

    """

    hdf_data = gdal.Open(path_to_hdf, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    subdataset_read = hdf_data.GetSubDatasets()[num]
    ds_sub = gdal.Open(subdataset_read[0],gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    return ds_sub.ReadAsArray()


def getCoordinateTransformerOutOfTheLambertProjectionToWGS():
    """

    Method for creating a tool to convert from Lambert to WGS

    return coordinate transformation, and projection

    """

    projection = 'PROJCS["Lambert_Conformal_Conic",' \
                             'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",' \
                             'DATUM["WGS_1984",' \
                             'SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137.0,298.252223563]],' \
                             'PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],' \
                             'UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],' \
                             'PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],' \
                             'PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],' \
                             'PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],' \
                             'PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",79.950619],' \
                             'PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",67.41206675],' \
                             'PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",43.58046825],' \
                             'PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],' \
                             'PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",55.4962675],' \
                             'UNIT["Meter",1]]'

    projection_wgs = '''GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    '''
    lambert = osr.SpatialReference()
    lambert.ImportFromWkt(projection)

    wgs84 = osr.SpatialReference()
    wgs84.ImportFromWkt(projection_wgs)
    return osr.CoordinateTransformation(wgs84, lambert), projection

def saveToFile(outputFileName, ncols, nrows, geotransform, projection, nodata):

    return "af"




if __name__ == "__main__":
    reflectance = getDataFromFile("SVI01_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5", 2)
    reflectance2 = getDataFromFile("SVI02_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5",2)
    reflectance3 = getDataFromFile("SVI03_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5",2)
    brightnessTemperature4 = getDataFromFile("SVI04_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5",0)
    brightnessTemperature5 = getDataFromFile("SVI05_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5",0)

    latitude = getDataFromFile("GIMGO_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5",1)
    longitude = getDataFromFile("GIMGO_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5",2)
    ###Температура
    file = hdf.File('SVI04_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5')
    brightnessTemperature4DataFactor = np.array(file['All_Data/VIIRS-I4-SDR_All/BrightnessTemperatureFactors'])[:2]
    file = hdf.File('SVI05_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5')
    brightnessTemperature5DataFactor = np.array(file['All_Data/VIIRS-I5-SDR_All/BrightnessTemperatureFactors'])[:2]
    ###3 канала 
    file = hdf.File('SVI01_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5')
    reflectanceDataFactor = np.array(file['All_Data/VIIRS-I1-SDR_All/ReflectanceFactors'])[:2]
    file = hdf.File('SVI02_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5')
    reflectance2DataFactor = np.array(file['All_Data/VIIRS-I2-SDR_All/ReflectanceFactors'])[:2]
    file = hdf.File('SVI03_npp_d20190716_t0808475_e0821357_b00001_c20190716104346439000_ipop_dev.h5')
    reflectance3DataFactor = np.array(file['All_Data/VIIRS-I3-SDR_All/ReflectanceFactors'])[:2]



    ct,projection = getCoordinateTransformerOutOfTheLambertProjectionToWGS()


    resolution = 375 #Размер пикселя
    latitudeMin = latitude[latitude[...,0]>-500].min() #Latitude min > -999 Non data
    latitudeMax = latitude[latitude[...,0]>-500].max() #Latitude max > -999 Non data
    longitudeMin = longitude[longitude[...,0]>-500].min() # Longitude min >-999 Non data
    longitudeMax = longitude[longitude[...,0]>-500].max() #Longitude max > -99 Non data

    mask = (latitude >= latitudeMin) * (latitude <= latitudeMax) * (longitude >= longitudeMin) * (longitude <= longitudeMax)

    z = np.array(ct.TransformPoints(
        np.array([[latitudeMax, latitudeMin],
                  [longitudeMin, latitudeMax],
                  [longitudeMax, latitudeMax],
                  [longitudeMin, latitudeMin],
                  [longitudeMax, latitudeMin]]
                )))[:, :2]

    height = (z[1:3, 1].max() - z[0, 1]) / resolution
    width = (z[-1, 0] - z[-2, 0]) / resolution

    x_min, y_max = z[-2, 0], z[1:3, 1].max()

    ncols = int(width)
    nrows = int(height)

    x_intervals = np.array(x_min + np.arange(ncols) * resolution)
    y_intervals = np.array(y_max- np.arange(nrows) * resolution)


    geotransform = [x_min, resolution, 0, y_max, 0, -resolution]
    del x_min
    del y_max
    del z
    print('Посчитаны геотрансформации')
    points = np.zeros(shape=(latitude[mask].shape[0], 2))
    points[:, 0] = longitude[mask]
    points[:, 1] = latitude[mask]
    print('Посчитаны point')
    coord = np.array(ct.TransformPoints(points))[:, :2]
    x_index = np.searchsorted(x_intervals, coord[:, 0], 'left')
    y_index = np.searchsorted(y_intervals[::-1], coord[:, 1], 'left')
    y_index = nrows - y_index - 1

    print('Посчитаны coordinate')

    mask_nodata = get_mask(x_index=x_index, y_index=y_index, ncols=ncols, nrows=nrows)
```

Comment: Какие команды выполняются дольше всего?

Comment: @MaxU вычисление x_index и y_index

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных (для 10-20 точек)? И что из себя представляют intervals?

Comment: Ещё неплохо было бы объяснить что вы пытаетесь сделать и для чего

Comment: @MaxU добавил часть кода, спасибо.

Comment: так все-таки что долго выполняется - `np.searchsorted(...)` или тот блок, что указан в первой части вопроса?

Comment: @MaxU points = np.zeros(shape=(latitude[mask].shape[0], 2))  да и np.searchsorted(...) тоже долго очень

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96338/discussion-between-denis-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в следующем блоке:

```
points = np.zeros(shape=(latitude[mask].shape[0], 2))
points[:, 0] = longitude[mask] 
points[:, 1] = latitude[mask]
```

`latitude[mask]` - вычисляется дважды. Этот код можно заменить на следующий:

```
points = np.column_stack((longitude[mask], latitude[mask]))
```

Comment: Спасибо, будет здорово если поможете ещё с np.searchsorted(x_intervals, coord[:, 0], 'left'), если нет и на том Спасибо)

Comment: @Denis, для того чтобы помочь с `np.searchsorted()` нужно понять что вы пытаетесь сделать и увидеть пример данных. `np.searchsorted()` сам по себе очень быстрый. Советую открыть новый вопрос и оформить его в соответствии с [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)